# pandasで特定の列の値に基づき，その行を複製する方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

`pandas.DataFrame`で特定の列の値の回数分，行を複製する方法を探しています．

下に示すソースコードは，`num`列の値と同じ個数になるように，行を複製しています．
しかしこれは恐らく最も効率が悪い方法です．効率的な方法が御座いましたらご教示下さい．

なお、操作前のデータフレームに同一の行は含まれないことが保証されています．

**現状のコード:**

```py
# Python 3.10.5

import pandas as pd

raw = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]], columns=['name', 'num'])
new = pd.DataFrame(columns=raw.columns)

for _, row in raw.iterrows():
    for _ in range(row.num):
        new = new.append(row)
```

**操作前のデータフレーム:**

```
    name    num
0   a       1
1   b       2
2   c       3
```

**操作後のデータフレーム:**

```
    name    num
0   a       1
1   b       2
1   b       2
2   c       3
2   c       3
2   c       3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> new = raw.iloc[raw.index.repeat(raw['num'])]
>>> new
  name  num
0    a    1
1    b    2
1    b    2
2    c    3
2    c    3
2    c    3
```